# PHP: Restricting access to the final page

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I'm trying to restrict the acccess to a php page. The file "calendario.php" should be only visible for the users previously logged on through "login.php"

The problem right now: if the user type manually the url in the browser, he can accesss directly without credentials. I managed to prevent this with a "if" but even so .The page loads the content for a moment, so if you are skilled enough you can pause the browser in the exact momento  and have access to the information.

This is what I tried so far:

### login.php

```
<?php
   include("required/datos.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['login']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$myusername' and BINARY password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


      if($count == 1) {
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
         $_SESSION['autorizado'] = TRUE;
         header('location: calendario.php');

      }else {

         $message = "Credenciales incorrectas";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
         header('Refresh: 0; URL=index.php');


      }
   }
?>
```

### calendario.php

```
<?php

require_once('required/bdd.php');
session_start(); 
?>

<?php
  if($_SESSION['autorizado']==true)
    { 

      echo '<li class="active" style="padding-left: 15px">';
      echo $_SESSION["login_user"];
      echo ' - ';
      echo '<a href="logout.php"><span>Desconectar</span></a></li>';
    }
  else
    {
      header('Refresh: 0; URL=index.php');
    }

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT id, title, start, end, color FROM events ";

$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();

$events = $req->fetchAll();


?>
```

I would like to know your opinion on how to improve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a proper redirect with a Location header
2. Don't output the content if they aren't authorised to see it. Stop the script before it gets to the part that generates the content.

Such:

```
{
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that worked...thank you. Which is the main diference between header('Refresh: 0; URL=index.php'); and header('Location: index.php');?

Comment: The former means "Here is a page. After some time: load a new page". The latter means "You asked for X but you should ask for Y instead, don't load this page at all".

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I will give you the tick when the system allows me to do.